# Set custom header in Backbone.js not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set a custom header in my `backbone.js` application in a `save` method. The header isn't being set, even though I can set the header successfully in a `fetch` method.

```
switch(method){
    case 'read' :
        model.fetch({
             headers:{
                 "Override-Authorization":'Basic ' + proxyAuth
             }
        });
        break;
    case 'create' || 'update' :
        sendAuthentication = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Override-Authorization','Basic ' + proxyAuth);
        };
        model.save({
            beforeSend:sendAuthentication,
            headers:{
                "Override-Authorization":'Basic ' + proxyAuth
            }
       });
       break;
    case 'delete' :
        model.delete({
            headers:{
                "Override-Authorization":'Basic ' + proxyAuth
            }
        });
        break;
    }
```

In the first case, with `fetch` call, the header gets set properly. In the second case, with the `save` method, the header isn't set, even though I've tried it both ways. Any thoughts?

Comment: `case 'create' || 'update' :` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: to expound on mu's comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Example:_Using_switch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the `Model#save`'s [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save).

```
model.save([attributes], [options])
```

You're actually setting some attributes to your model instead of overriding the headers.

```
model.save({}, {
  beforeSend:sendAuthentication,
  headers:{
    "Override-Authorization":'Basic ' + proxyAuth
  }
});
```

will do the trick.